# Cron not working automatically for Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, cron

I configured `cron` in Drupal 7 for every 1 hour to delete "watchdog" table data. However, it is not working fine as expected when done automatically, even though it is working fine manually. What could be the problem with `cron` running automatically for specified intervals of time? Please, kindly help me with any alternate options, if possible.

Comment: Add cron.php to the cron tasks in your hosting CP

Comment: I even tried cron.php with hosting cron but no result. Finally, i set up custom coding & deleted records by calling this custom file from hosting cron. I don't know, is it right procedure or not.. Give me a suggestion, if any..

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

Maybe one of your installed modules has a bad implementation of [hook_cron()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7). An error in this hook would provoke the whole cron process to fail. You can use [Cron Debug module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cron_debug) to check which of the modules is failing during the cron execution. After that, you may consider disabling the module, or checking what is going wrong and fixing it.

Hope it helps.